# How do I check if a field is in a specific document in pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

How do I check if a field is in a specific document in pymongo?

My code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def a9djasdjasdamdasmdkasmdiasnda8231(ctx):
  kekw = str(ctx.author.id)
  query = {"user": kekw, "moooney": {"$exists": True}}
  cursor = db.maindb.find(query)
  for cursor in cursor:
    print(cursor)
    await ctx.send(cursor)
```

Its supposed to be sending either true or false, depending if the field is in the document.
Although it doesn't print or send anything. But i know the value moooney exists.

It would help a lot if someone tells me what im doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that there aren't any answers yet. If anyone's reading this, please let me know if there's something I can do to make the question clearer.

Comment: your query already takes care of ensuring the the field exists, so I don't see what's the point in double checking. also, you can't have a line like "for cursor in cursor" - use a different name for your iterator! like "for record in cursor". then you can easily check: if "moooney" in record , like checking if a exists in a dict.